# Critic badge awarded incorrectly

Tags: support, badges

I recently accidentally clicked on the down vote button on a question. I promptly re-clicked it to undo my down vote which worked perfectly. However, I ended up receiving the Critic badge which is described as "First down vote".

I have never down voted anything before as I'm fairly new in my Stack Overflow career so I'm certain it was from this undone action.

Is this deliberate or a (very) minor bug?

Comment: You do know that one is supposed to want the badges, right? If you get enough of them, you can go to heaven, I've heard...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This isn't a bug, but intended behavior.

The badge was awarded due to taking some corrective action on a post by another person (in this case a downvote).

Though it was done by mistake, the system has no way to know that. And badges are not revoked, so... enjoy your new shiny badge :)

Comment: Thanks Oded. I was expecting the badge would only be added after the vote grace period had expired but it makes sense the way it is. I'll wear my new badge with pride :)

Comment: Same thing happened to me when i first upvote and suddenly realize something to be looked into so, did undo, Still Supporter badge awarded. Happy to know that, thank you Oded.

Comment: "Though it was done by mistake, the system has no way to know that": perhaps it will change sometime- no-one really wants a badge for doing something unintended. Do they?