# How did I receive the critic badge even though I haven't downvoted anything?

Tags: support, badges

I have been awarded the [Critic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732) for my first downvote. I do not recall downvoting anything, and my votes table does not show any downvotes. So, what does it mean?

Comment: Maybe you downvoted something and removed your vote?

Comment: Not that I recall, and I did not know you could remove a vote.

Comment: Could be that you double-clicked by accident. A second click undoes a vote. But only within a certain time frame. So it would track if you misclicked or something similar. Although it might also be a bug.

Comment: Its possible I double touched. I was on a mobile phone at the time I think. If a vote can be undone (within a limited time period) it would be a design flaw for it to be counted anywhere at all?

Comment: I would ask why you haven't already used a downvote prior. Downvotes are important, please use them more. :)

Comment: @petern0691 You can undo a downvote within a certain time period, after which it is locked in. You can then undo said vote only if the post is edited. After a certain number of applying and undoing a vote on a given post, you are blocked by the system from voting on that post anymore... I think it's like 10 or 15 times (just FYI).

Comment: Maybe deep inside, you're really a critic and that's showing up without even needing to fulfill any criteria.

Comment: You can see all of your votes by visiting your vote history page on your main site profile - https://stackoverflow.com/users/16015991/petern0691?tab=votes&sort=downvote

Comment: I know. And it shows no down votes.

Comment: So for my edification, why has this question been down voted? Such does not encourage people to try to understand how things work here.

Comment: Badges are awarded when a particular action occurs. We can't explain why you received a badge for downvoting and can't remember downvoting. We can see that you currently have no existing downvotes, but that doesn't really change a whole lot... given you've received the badge, Congratulations on your badge, and i hope this alleged accidental downvote isn't the only downvote you ever... don't cast. ;)

Comment: Looking at recent users who've been awarded the badge, most have in fact cast their first downvote, though there are a few who are also at none just as you are. I can only assume it was a cast and then reverse in all of these cases, as if the badge was just being given out to everyone a whole lot more people would have it

Comment: Interesting... do y'all not see retracted votes in your vote history? I can... but I never remember what is because I'm special. I can't imagine why we'd hide that, though.

Comment: @Catija I'm thinking it's a Staff or Mod-only feature (or just because you're otherwise "special" ).  Where do you see it?  Under "Votes" in my Activity, I show *All*, *Upvote*, *Downvote*, *Deletion*, *Undeletion*, and *Reopen*.  Nothing that I can see that would be related under *All actions* either.

Comment: @Catija Just as a test, I downvoted a random question, refreshed, and checked my *All votes*.  The downvote showed in the history.  Then I retracted the vote, refreshed the question again, refreshed my activity again - The vote was simply removed from the history -- No "Retracted" or anything like that.

Comment: On the theory that this might be a double-click, retracted vote, I tested on ServerFault, where I have downvote-privileges, and do not have the Critic badge.  A retracted downvote did not trigger the badge.

Comment: @petern0691 *"So for my edification, why has this question been down voted? Such does not encourage people to try to understand how things work here."* -- Downvotes on Meta don't really work the same way that they do on the main site.  Here, they mean more of a "agree" or "disagree", which I know doesn't *quite* fit in this case either.  But think of as something like -- 12 people think they already know why this is happen and/or don't care, and 5 people (currently) do want to better understand why things are working (or not) the way they are.

Comment: On the point above re more down voting: Apart from my FQ well over a year ago I have only been active for the last ~6 weeks and have only had voting rights for a few weeks, so I am still getting my head around what is considered to be the good, the bad, and the ugly.

Comment: Perhaps you voted on a post and then that post got deleted? Up/down votes on deleted questions are not listed on the Votes tab on one's profile (even for 10k+ users, which is... weird because other types of votes are listed).

Comment: @Catija Nope, although we can see retracted close-votes (with no indication that they're retracted ‍♂️) _and_ close-votes on deleted questions, we don't get to see retracted up/down votes, nor do we see up/down votes on deleted questions (for mysterious reasons :D).

Comment: This is, minimally, weird enough that a documented answer on how it happened would be useful. At worst, this is actually some kind of bug. You got the award 30 minutes after posting an answer. Do you remember doing anything at all between the time you posted the answer and getting the badge?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds is it possible you didn't leave the vote up long enough? Not that I think you should risk permanently sticking someone with a down vote but maybe the code awarding the badge waits a minute or two (but not the full five minutes before you can't retract it) before awarding it?

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for pinging on this -- Without having changed any additional votes on ServerFault, I now have the Critic badge, so I just didn't [wait long enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/902710) -- I should have checked the FAQ on that first.  So a rapidly-retracted downvote *did* trigger the award, even though the batch process to award it didn't run until later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on some testing, I think you probably received *Critic* based on a double-click or double-tap on the *Downvote* button (originally proposed as a theory by @VLAZ in the comments).

As mentioned in the comments, I tried to test this yesterday by downvoting a random question on ServerFault, where I have downvoting privileges but did not have the Critic badge.  I quickly retracted the vote a few seconds later to avoid having it stick.

While I mentioned in the comments that this did *not* trigger the Critic badge, I was wrong -- I simply didn't [wait long enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/902710).  When I checked again today, I now have the Critic badge.  The retracted downvote *did* trigger its award, but it didn't show up until the batch process ran -- probably within the hour of when I tried it, since both my comment above and [the award](https://serverfault.com/help/badges/7/critic) show as 19 hours ago currently.

Interestingly, the *notification* of being awarded Critic badge still does *not* show up in my "Achievements" (the trophy icon) Notifications even though other badge awards do.

Comment: Can the documentation for the Critic badge be updated to advise accordingly, which is where I went initially. I note that I am not the first to have this "problem" and presumably will not be the last, eg, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308641/i-seem-to-have-been-awarded-the-critic-badge-incorrectly?rq=1) and there are others too.

Comment: @petern0691 Well, I don't know that documenting it is necessarily the right thing to do, as it seems to me to be an "unintended behavior."  It's not like you just want to tell people "double-click on the downvote button to get the badge but not have it count as an actual downvote" ;-).  I mean, sure, they can read it here and do it, but putting the info directly on the badge help seems unnecessary.

Comment: And the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308641/11810933) you linked to was caused by a different issue -- A deleted question after the vote.  Not saying that you are the first to have this happen, but you may (not sure if there is another potential duplicate) be the first person to notice it!

Comment: "the notification of being awarded Critic badge still does not show up" After a certain point (association bonus maybe?) they stop giving you notifications for "trivial" badges. Otherwise you would get a lot of pointless notifications.

Comment: Sorry re duplicate. I meant to link [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266675/critic-badge-awarded-incorrectly).

Comment: Re documentation. A long long time ago I was told, "If the bug/design flaw is not damaging, and does not NEED fixing  then document it and call it a feature."